# Why is `join` also known as `mu`?

Tags: functional-programming, monads, idris

I noticed in the Idris documentation that `join` is also known as `flatten` and `mu`.

```
Idris> :doc join
Prelude.Monad.join : Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
    Also called flatten or mu

    The function is Total
```

IIRC, `mu` (or μ) is used as a binder for recursive data types. I've not seen `mu` in this context before. What's the background on that?

Comment: Does `mu` stand for `monadic unit`?

Comment: I don't think so, I think it's the greek letter, μ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very short answer: category theory.

The medium length answer:
If you look at the [formal definition of a Monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Formal_definition) on Wikipedia (sorry, not copying it over since there is no LaTeX support on SO), you'll see "mu" and "eta" used as the two "[natural transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation)", where mu is the one from T2 to T (which makes sense if you look at the type signature, which goes from (`m (m a)` to `m a`).

The in-depth answer: [Monads Made Difficult](http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/monads.html) (see "Natural Transformations")